# Creating Webservice in PHP to use with clients applications written in PHP, VB.net, Android

Tags: php, android, vb.net, json, web-services

i am going to provide a webservice to customers. Idea is to provide a common platform for a number of customers. Customers have to register in my site by filling some details and i will issue them GREEN signal for using this service. And i will give them a vb.net and android application that uses this webservice and also a sample php application to use it in their website if needed.

Each customer is considered as an organization. So they can add employees, check employee details, company details, add products, etc. These db operations are done using my webservice. I have read w3school's tutorial about webservices. I didnot understood SOAP architecture clearly. But i know about JSON. And in PHP echoing json output is easy because we need to call json_encode passing array.

But i donot know how to do authentication. I mean login to webservice application from client application with userame and password. Will storing value in SESSION works, like a normal php application ? For client, will it save session in cookie ?
What is easiest architecture to use? JSON? Is it possible? Please share any reference links that you bookmarked, if you were doing something like this.

I donot want to use a complex way. Please help me.I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you think SOAP protocols are tougher for you and not necessary, you could easily implement using REST based protocols. All REST methods are fairly simple and straightforward and easy to implement using PHP.

I recommend REST, because it can be easily adapter to both Java(Android) and VB.NET based application.

Read more in [Google for REST + PHP](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=php%20rest&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&safe=active)

Instead of building a application from scratch, see if you can start with a framework such as Zend Framework.

For example, if a client wants to add a new employee, he will issue a `POST` request to your server with the employee details in the POST arguments. If he wants to get the details of a particular employee, he will issue a `GET` request with the employee ID.

And as you said, for sending the output to the client, you can use JSON as that is lightweight, readable and works with minimum code.

Regarding authentication via web services, there are multiple methods to approach. One is classic username and password. On each request, the client need to pass the username and password in the URL parameters along with other parameters. But this is less secure to expose the password.

A stronger method is to use access token, where you will issue a random token to each client on first access and ask the client to provide the same in subsequent calls. You should invalidate this token after a selected period.

Searching in [Stackoverflow for Webserverices + Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=web%20service%20authentication) will give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

A good framework to expose your app operations over an API is Apify: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ptoB0yCsDo & http://www.apifydoc.com/

This library makes you focus on the actual business logic without having to write code for different type of output & stuff.

Comment: then how to use in my project? I read installation guide. But no examples shown in site

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you looking at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) tutorial.
It can solve your issue.